what is the use of .format_prompt() in langchain when creating prompt templates?
In the code snippet below, I was not able to understand the use of -
format_prompt(features=features)
in the return value of the function.
def analyze_cons(features):
    cons_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", "You are an expert product reviewer."),
            (
                "human",
                "Given these features: {features}, list the cons of these features.",
            ),
        ]
    )
    return cons_template.format_prompt(features=features)

Can someone help me understand the use of this?
I tried the code without .format_prompt() in the return function and the code works as expected.

.format_prompt() is for implementing the features parameter into the cons_template.
Example
Lets say: features="Lightweight, Responsive"
By using:
cons_template.format_prompt(features=Lightweight, Responsive')

Your code will return:
messages=[SystemMessage(content='You are an expert product reviewer.', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}), HumanMessage(content='Given these features: Lightweight, Responsive, list the cons of these features.', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={})]

Replacing the original {features} inside the cons_template with
Lightweight, Responsive.
